# Python - Create a join condition from lists

Tags: python

I have two lists for two tables with their key columns

```
keycol1 = [col1,col2]
keycol2 = [col3,col4]
```

I want to frame a sql query with these two colums as join condition

```
for column1,column2 in zip(keycol1,keycol2):   
    join = "table1."+ column1 + " = " + "table2." + column2 and
qry = "select * from table1 join table2 on " + join
```

But this gives me an extra `and` at the end. How to avoid it?

Expected query:

```
select * from table1 join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col3 and  table1.col2 = table2.col4
```

Comment: Fix the syntax errors first

Comment: Possibly he typed it here instead of copy pasting.

Comment: You should not use `+` an strings and you must not use it on SQL query strings.

Comment: `''.join(["table1.", column1, " = table2.", column2])` is more efficient than repeatedly concatenating two strings, but the main issue is constructing ad-hoc SQL like this, at least without validating the values of `keycol1` and `keycol2` first. A better idea is to find a good SQL library that constructs the query for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
keycol1 = ['col1', 'col2']
keycol2 = ['col3', 'col4']

join = ' and '.join(['table1.{0} = table2.{1}'.format(c1, c2) \
                     for c1, c2 in zip(keycol1, keycol2)])

qry = "select * from table1 join table2 on " + join 

# 'select * from table1 join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col3 and table1.col2 = table2.col4'
```

**Explanation**

- Use a list comprehension with `str.format` to form each condition.
- Combine your conditions using `' and '.join()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using the `map` function along with `join`:

```
keycol1 = ['col1', 'col2']
keycol2 = ['col3', 'col4']

for column1,column2 in zip(keycol1,keycol2):   
    joined = " and ".join(map(lambda c: "table1."+ c[0] + " = " + "table2." + c[1], zip(keycol1, keycol2)))

qry = "select * from table1 join table2 on " + joined

print(qry)
```

Output:

```
select * from table1 join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col3 and table1.col2 = table2.col4
```